# Passwordless keybased authentication not working

Tags: authentication, ssh, debian-stretch, password-less

this is what I need to realize:

1. keybased passwordless authentication for user `root`
2. passwordbased authentication for any other user than root

Server I need to have access to is running Debian 9 (stretch).

On my client I have I have created a keypair like this: `ssh-keygen`

This created the following files `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Now I copied the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server and modified the keyfile with permission 600.

Then I modified the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on server by setting the following values:

`PermitRootLogin without-password
PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Now I restarted ssh service on server and tried the connection by `ssh root@sub.domain.tld`.

It still ends in password prompt for user `root`.

The outcome of `ssh -vvv root@sub.domain.tld` you can find [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gwXbs5zF8j/) (Ubuntu Pastebin).

What did I miss to modify?

Kind regards
//neph

Answer (score -1):

You should follow [this](http://www.justgohome.co.uk/blog/2013/07/better-two-factor-ssh-authentication-on-ubuntu.html) tutorial, there's a lot of outdated ones. It worked for me on Ubuntu 19.04.

```
All you have to do is:

apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator.

Users who want to continue using ssh must each run the command google-authenticator. This tool interatively helps you to create the file ~/.google_authenticator, which contains a shared secret and emergency passcodes. It's a terminal application, but it does still display a QR code for quick loading of the shared secret into your two factor device (in my case, this is the Google Authenticator app on my Android smartphone).

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Set:

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive

In case you have changed them in the past, you should also check the following two settings (these are both defaults on Ubuntu):

UsePAM yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

Run sudo service ssh reload to pick up your changes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Edit /etc/pam.d/sshd and replace the line:

@include common-auth

with:

auth required pam_google_authenticator.so

That's it! Now ssh logins will require a key, and after your key is verified will additionally require proof that you hold your second factor device.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refrain from posting links as your answer, as links die over time.  Take the relevant information from the article and post it here with an explanation.

Comment: ive put the relevent information in the answer! There's more in-depth information in the link that didn't seem relevant to the specific question.